# How exactly ORDER BY works?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query:

```
. . . ORDER BY col1 desc, col2, col3 desc
```

It should be noted `col2` is unique. So I want to know writing `col3 desc` is useless or sometimes it may be useful?

In general, I want to know can I remove every column name which is written after an unique column on the `ORDER BY` clause?

Comment: *I want to know can I remove every column name which is written after an unique column on the ORDER BY clause?* - Yes.

Comment: @AgRizzo Thank you .. I needed to hear that.

Comment: Watch out for more complicated collation rules if sorting textual data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order by works from left to right (as with other expressions) so, yes, if a column is unique then subsequent columns in the *order by* will be redundant.
Personally, I would expect any SQL engine worth its salt would optimise away the redundant columns.

edit..

As mentioned by Frederick in comments - It is possible that unique text columns held in one collation and then selected and ordered in another collation could create duplicates on that column. In such a situation the *order by* might not behave as I have described above but your script will most likely have collation hints so you should hopefully be aware of the risk.

Comment: If you were being very nit picky you could have distinct text sequences that were equal in the chosen collation (eg ß (eszett) and ss in German).

Comment: @Frederick --  Ah! yes.   As I was writting it, I was trying to think of a plausable case were it might not apply.  You are right of course but in dozens of years of experience I've never come across that scenario. I hope I never do, as I'll probably be scratching my head for a good while should it ever crop up!